# Change currency on product collection

Tags: currency

How do i change this

```
$special_price = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->special_price, false, false);
```

To show for example Euros? can i put in some parameter? im making some CSV lists, and i need to be able to edit the currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show another currency of product price.

First, you need find out the currency code.

```
$currentCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$allowedCurrencies = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies(); 
$allowedRates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates($currentCode, array_values($allowedCurrencies));
```

$allowedRates will give you all rates of currency base on current currency code. Therefore, you can calculate the another currency price what you want.